# How to import ACE code editor into vue without using its vue component?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, npm, ace-editor

Beginner in vue here. I would want to use ace code editor ([this package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ace-code) ) in vue.

For learning purposes, I don't want to use the vue2-component & vue3-component versions of the ace editor. How to do to it?

**Why do I want to do this?**

I am a programmer from pre-jquery era.Catching upto modern web development, starting with Vue. I noticed that lot of Vue component packages aren't upto date with their plain JS library conterparts. I want to learn this so that I can use any non-vue library in vue.

**EDIT:**

As per the first answer, The editor is working but the syntax highlighting & themes aren't working in the code editor. Probably, style sheets aren't loading or working.

I get the following errors in the console though. I have no clue about what else should be configuring.

[image]

**EDIT 2:**

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So i tried to use the code provided by Andres Abadia but even with it i'm getting the error:

`loader is not configured`

(by the way if your using js remove the `lang="ts"` from the script tag)

But `ace-code` is working so where it goes wrong and why it does not load themes ?

[image: Loader Not Configured]

The actual problem is you're using the `ace-code` package raw files like you was going to use them on an out Framework world but if you wanted to use some highlights or some other feature from it you couldn't load them because you'll have to use some `scripts` via `CDN` and import them one by one and you'll have some issues with the `defined key` so what i propose you to use directly use the package needed who is [`ace-builds`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ace-builds) with the all generated file to use (of course i will give you some snippet for Vue2 & Vue3) but there is a specification and thanks to the `Ace` team in this package they provide a `webpack-resolver` who will make your loader (Webpack in your case otherwise the error will be different with Vite if i'm not wrong) load all the files and understand them so like this you can use the snippets below and work with your pretty third part library `Ace code`

Don't forget to install `file-loader` as a devDependencie to load the generated file from the `ace-builds` package

You will still have an require error that comes from the library it use some require but with all the information i gaved you you can see some loader or some transpilador like `Babel` to make it work from your `CommonJS` to `ES6`

[image: TADAAA]

For Vue2:

```js
<template>
  <div class="ace-container">
    <!-- ID is used in official documents, it is forbidden to use it here, it is easy to cause problems after packaging later, just use ref or DOM -->
    <div class="ace-editor" ref="ace"></div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import ace from'ace-builds'
import'ace-builds/webpack-resolver'
import'ace-builds/src-noconflict/theme-monokai'
import'ace-builds/src-noconflict/mode-javascript'

export default {
  mounted () {
    this.aceEditor = ace.edit(this.$refs.ace, {
      maxLines: 20,
      minLines: 10,
      fontSize: 14,
      theme: this.themePath,
      mode: this.modePath,
      tabSize: 4
    })
  },
  data () {
    return {
      aceEditor: null,
      themePath:'ace/theme/monokai',//If webpack-resolver is not imported, the module path will report an error
      modePath:'ace/mode/javascript'//Same as above
    }
  }
}
</script>

<style scoped>
.ace-editor {
  width: 100%;
  height: 400px;
}
</style>
```

Vue3:

```js
<template>
  <div class="ace-container">
    <!-- ID is used in official documents, it is forbidden to use it here, it is easy to cause problems after packaging later, just use ref or DOM -->
    <div id="editor"></div>
  </div>
</template>

<script setup>
import {onMounted} from "vue";
import ace from "ace-builds";
import 'ace-builds/webpack-resolver'
import 'ace-builds/src-noconflict/theme-clouds';
import 'ace-builds/src-noconflict/mode-latex';


onMounted(() => {
  ace.edit('editor', {
    maxLines: 20,
    minLines: 10,
    fontSize: 14,
    theme: 'ace/theme/monokai',
    mode: 'ace/mode/javascript',
    tabSize: 4
  })
});
</script>

<style scoped>
#editor {
  width: 100%;
  height: 400px;
}
</style>
```

Comment: Hello I tried your Vue2 code on my own project, now the editor isn't loading at all. I got this error https://i.stack.imgur.com/0SKkb.png

Comment: I tried the same in codesandbox, https://codesandbox.io/s/vue2-ace-editor-ebk8sx

Comment: I tried it in a another code Sandbox but it seems like Code Sandbox doesn't like the `ace-builds` dependencie can you try in local and tell me pls

Comment: Claws i forgot to tell you that you have to install `file-loader` as a devDependencies to make it work, it's a file loader module for webpack who will help you to resolve `import/require()` that are used by the `ace-builds` package

Comment: Thank you. Its working beautifully. One question though, how did you figure out all of these to make it work. I am asking this to understand what should I be reading about to fill gaps in my knowledge.

Answer (score 1):

Using third party libraries is super easy with vue. I'm guessing your using some kind of package manager like `npm` to install `ace-code`. Just install the library and import it in the component you want to use it. I replicate the first example of the [ace docs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ace-code).

Ace code component:

```html
AceCode.vue

<script setup lang="ts">
import { onMounted } from "vue";
import ace from "ace-code";
onMounted(() => {
  ace.edit("editor");
});
</script>

<template>
  <div id="editor"></div>
</template>

<style scoped>
#editor {
  position: absolute;
  width: 500px;
  height: 400px;
}
</style>
```

As you see the `css` and `html` is the same just the logic has to change a bit. Wait for vue to render the html and after that call the `edit` method. You can do this by using the [`onMounted`](https://vuejs.org/api/composition-api-lifecycle.html#onmounted) method from vue.

Comment: Hello the editor is loading but highlighting, keyboard shortcuts, themes etc aren't working. I changed the code to `var editor = ace.edit("editor");
        editor.setTheme("ace/theme/clouds");
        editor.session.setMode("ace/mode/latex");` but still no luck!

Comment: Oh! I think keyboard shortcuts are working. I couldn't see the highlighting & themes because style sheets aren't getting loaded or working. Is there anything that needs to be done for that? Should I be importing something else? I've edited the question and added screenshot.